# UITableView: NSMutableArray not appearing in table

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm new to objective c and iPhone programming. I can't seem to figure out why no cells will fill when I run this code. The xml content displays in the console log and xcode displays no errors. Can any help?

```
    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if(![elementName compare:@"Goal"]) {
        tempElement = [[xmlGoal alloc] init];
    } else if (![elementName compare:@"Title"]) {
        currentAttribute = [NSMutableString string];
    } else if (![elementName compare:@"Progress"]) {
        currentAttribute = [NSMutableString string];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if (![elementName compare:@"Goal"])  {
        [xmlElementObjects addObject:tempElement];
    } else if (![elementName compare:@"Title"]) {
        NSLog(@"The Title of this event is %@", currentAttribute);
        [tempElement setTitled:currentAttribute];
     } else if (![elementName compare:@"Progress"]) {
        NSLog(@"The Progress of this event is %@", currentAttribute);
        [tempElement setProgressed:currentAttribute];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (self.currentAttribute) {
        [self.currentAttribute appendString:string];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [xmlElementObjects count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [mtableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    // Set up the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [xmlElementObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I can't seem to figure out why no
>   cells will fill when I run this code.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [xmlElementObjects count];
}
```

Is this method getting hit? If so, is `xmlElementObjects` `nil`? If not, is it returning 0 since there are no elements in the array? If so, is it because your XML parsing code didn't fill the array before the array is being used?

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you need to check: Did you set the dataSource property of your tableview to the correct object? Other than that, check if your `if(![elementName compare:@"Goal"])` is really 'hit' (either by NSLog()ing or putting a breakpoint there.

Another note, and unrelated, you should probably release `tempElement` after adding it to the `xmlElements` dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Set breakpoints in `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to ensure that they're being called. As Alfons mentioned, it may be that your table view's `datasource` property is not being set.

Some unrelated notes:

1. Why are you using the statement `![someString compare:someOtherString]` for comparison? `NSString` has a built-in `-isEqualToString:` method, so you can replace that statement with `[someString isEqaulToString:someOtherString]`. Your results won't change, but your code will benefit from the added readability.
2. In `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you have the following code:

   ```
   UITableViewCell *cell = [mtableview
                             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   ```

   This might cause problems if you keep using the instance variable (in this case, `mtableview`) here. The method has a table view as an argument, so use `tableView` instead. That will ensure that you dequeue a cell from the table view that called this method.
3. Are you developing for iPhone OS 3.0 or above? If so, the line

   ```
   [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero
                          reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   ```

   should be replaced with

   ```
   [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                          reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   ```

   using whichever cell style you'd like, naturally.

Answer (score 0):

Well `xmlElementObjects` isn't a array of strings, it contains instances to some custom class you've created (I assume). Thus, when you say `cell.textLabel.text = [xmlElementObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`, you're setting a `NSString` to some unknown object.

Try `cell.textLabel.text = [[xmlElementObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] titled];`

(I'm guessing the title name from the parsing code)

Answer (score -1):

Objective C is very new to me. I am used to writing PHP which seems very easy compared to this so far. I set the datasource and also change compare to isequaltostring. This is what the console log states now:

2010-04-07 02:28:16.580 bucket list[6449:20b] The Title of this event is 
        Test 1
        10%

2010-04-07 02:28:16.581 bucket list[6449:20b] The Title of this event is 
        Test 2
        20%

2010-04-07 02:28:16.584 list[6449:20b] *** -[xmlGoal isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3d36600
2010-04-07 02:28:16.585 list[6449:20b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[xmlGoal isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3d36600'

I appreciate all the help!

Comment: Do not reply to your own question with an answer. Edit your original post instead.